# jQuery - if text in DIV was clicked

Tags: jquery, css, html, select

I have some DIVs. Inside these DIVs are some texts, images, tags... I need to show "alert", when text is clicked. Not images, not other tags, not text in other tags... just text inside DIVs. How to do it with jQuery ?

[jsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/TUnJq/)

HTML

```
<div style="background-color:PapayaWhip;">Some text. 
 <img src="http://ynternet.sk/test2/close_1.jpg" /> 
 <img src="http://ynternet.sk/test2/close_2.jpg" /> 
</div> 
<div style="background-color:Moccasin;">This are letters 
 <em>and this are not.</em> 
 Hello again!
</div> 
<div style="background-color:LightGoldenRodYellow;">
 <img src="http://ynternet.sk/test2/close_1.jpg" />
 <img src="http://ynternet.sk/test2/close_2.jpg" />
 Letters in new line.
 <img src="http://ynternet.sk/test2/close_1.jpg" />
 <img src="http://ynternet.sk/test2/close_2.jpg" /> 
</div> 
<div style="background-color:Wheat;">New letters in another line.</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  padding:10px 0px 0px 20px;
  font-family:Verdana;
  height:40px;
}
em{
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: @user1232020 Not at all relevant to this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the type of source if div then it means it would be text wrapped directly by the div. If you want to include mode tag like `em` then you can add those in condition.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TUnJq/2/)**

```
$('div').click(function(evt){  
    if(evt.target.tagName == 'DIV')
        alert("div clicked");
});
```

Comment: This is really the best answer. It doesn't require any changes to the HTML and uses the minimum number of event handlers. It wouldn't handle nested `<div>` elements, but the question doesn't indicate that's a requirement or possibility, so no need to do so.

Answer (score 6):

You could use some jQuery magic and look at the children of the `div`, however I would add a `span` or `label` inside your divs and give it a class/id:

```
<span class="letters">
  Letters in new line
</span>

$(".letters").click(function() {
    alert('Clicked');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/meNJu/

The fiddle provided shows how to use it with `children()` as well as the method mentioned above.

http://jsfiddle.net/meNJu/1/

Demonstrating using a class rather than an ID.

Comment: Better off using a class, since the `id` attribute of every element on the page should be unique.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist true. Adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the propagation of the event from all children of the divs:

```
$('div').click(function (event) {
    alert('Text');
});
$('div').children().click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/TUnJq/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Would it not be viable to use a 
    Span with the class text

With this code

```
$(".text").click(function() {
 alert("Handler for click() called.");
});
```

( answer posted from phone,  untested code.  Post will be spellchecked once at a pc )

Comment: In heine sight you could use would ..   $('div').text().click(function {}).  Work

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple:

```
$('div').click(function (e) {

    if ($(this).children().length === 0) {
        // do something
        alert($(this).text());
    }
});

$('div').children().click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TUnJq/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understood correctly what you're trying to do, you will need to do the following:

html

```
<div>
    <span class="click">This are letters</span>
    <em>and this are not.</em> 
    Hello again!
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.click').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).html()):
});
```

This was just a very simple example but it may help you